# TreeView nodes not being displayed

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, treeview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XAML Code for TREEVIEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004356/xaml-code-for-treeview)

Following is the code for TreeView in XAML:

```xml
<TreeView Height="338" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0"
          Name="DisksTreeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="293">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Namee}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

And following is the code behind:

```
Dim adpt As New DatabaseDearDataSetTableAdapters.DiskListTableAdapter
For Each k As KeyValuePair(Of String, GenreSet) In GenreSetDictionary
    Dim t As New TreeNodeSet
    t.Genre = True
    t.Imagepath = k.Value.IconPath
    t.Namee = k.Key
    Dim pnode As New TreeViewItem
    pnode.DataContext = t
    For Each z As DatabaseDearDataSet.DiskListRow In adpt.GetDataByGenre(t.Namee)
        Dim tt As New TreeNodeSet
        tt.Genre = False
        tt.Imagepath = IconDictionary(z.DiskIcon).IconPath
        tt.Namee = z.DiskName
        Dim cnode As New TreeViewItem
        cnode.DataContext = tt
        pnode.Items.Add(cnode)
    Next
    DisksTreeView1.Items.Add(pnode)
Next
```

I am able to get the `pnode` added to the TreeView and all the node breakpoints are hit.  The problem is that in the TreeView, I am only able to see the parent view arrow, the rest of the name, image, etc. are not getting displayed. It is like this:

[image: Sample picture]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Following is the Immediate window error: System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='TreeViewItem'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for the above issue is displayed at the following page:
[XAML and Required Code Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004356/xaml-code-for-treeview)

Answer (score 0):

In your code-behind you are creating a `TreeViewItem` instances and adding them to the TreeView. But what you need to do - is to define your model classes in a hierarchical way, bind top level items collection to the `ItemsSource` property of the `TreeView`, and use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` instead of the `DataTemplate` to display nested items.

Comment: I reviewed the net for the whole day, but I am fed up on this, I am not able to get a simple to understand solution.  Is it possible for you to give a sample easy to understand with not much technical stuff please.