# XAML Code for TREEVIEW

Tags: wpf, vb.net, treeview

Following is the code I wrote for generating treeview hierarchy,

```
    For Each k As KeyValuePair(Of String, GenreSet) In GenreSetDictionary
        Dim t As New TreeNodeSet
        t.Genre = True
        t.Imagepath = k.Value.IconPath
        t.Namee = k.Key
        Dim pnode As New TreeViewItem
        pnode.DataContext = t
        pnode.Visibility = True
        For Each z As DatabaseDearDataSet.DiskListRow In adpt.GetDataByGenre(t.Namee)
            Dim tt As New TreeNodeSet
            tt.Genre = False
            tt.Imagepath = IconDictionary(z.DiskIcon).IconPath
            tt.Namee = z.DiskName
            Dim cnode As New TreeViewItem
            cnode.DataContext = tt
            pnode.Items.Add(cnode)
        Next
        DisksTreeView1.Items.Add(pnode)
    Next
```

Following is the code I have used in XAML:

```xml
<TreeView Height="211" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,15,0,0" Name="TreeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="346">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Namee}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

However, I was not able to get that work, could you please tell me where my XAML went wrong please.

Comment: Because you add items explicitly using the code like `DisksTreeView1.Items.Add`, but datatemplate works only for items in the `ItemsSource` property. I would create a correct example, but your code uses data sets, and I haven't ever worked with them.

Comment: @vorrtex: I'd suggest you still post it as an answer since it does answer the question in principle, there is no inherent need for explicit correct code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few minor mismatches here: the name of the `TreeView` control (TreeView1 or DisksTreeView1) and the `ImagePath` property (or `Imagepath`, c# is sensible to the register of variables).

But the main reason of the incorrect behavior is that the `ItemTemplate` property is applied to the `ItemsSource` property, not to the `Items` property.

Here are two possible ways to correct the code:

1) Fixeing of the data class, item template and binding to the ItemsSource

- Create the `myObservableCollection` private field of the type `ObservableCollection(Of TreeNodeSet)`.
- Add to the constructor the line `DisksTreeView1.ItemsSource = myObservableCollection`
- Change the line `DisksTreeView1.Items.Add(pnode)` to the line `myObservableCollection.Add(t)`.
- Add the `Disks` property to the `TreeNodeSet` class (the type is `ObservableCollection` too)
- In the xaml replace the line with `DataTemplate` to the line `<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Disks}"`
- Change the line `pnode.Items.Add(cnode)` to the line `t.Disks.Add(tt)`.

2) Using the `HeaderTemplate` property instead of the `ItemTemplate` property.

At first, move the DataTemplate to resources and add some key. Then add a similar code near each `TreeViewItem` in the code-behind:

```
    Dim pnode As New TreeViewItem
    pnode.DataContext = t
    pnode.Header = t
    pnode.HeaderTemplate = Resources("someKey")
```

Comment: You are awesome Vortex, I used the first method and it worked pretty well and thanks for a clear description on step by step process to be followed.  I was able to achieve it now.  Sorry for delayed reply, I out of town for few days.  But I have a small doubt, how to declare TreeNodeSet as template type?

Comment: @surpavan By the phrase 'TreeNodeSet template type' I meant the type after the particle 'Of' in the line `ObservableCollection(Of TreeNodeSet)`. But I think too that this wording is unclear, so I'll edit the first step.

Comment: Thanks @vorrtex, what ever the terminology is, my problem is solved and I learned it and applied in few more areas also.  Thanks for the help once again.